# What is the bait and switch method in Classical Western Music?

Tags: piano

I am stuck in a melody because i am using in-harmonic A minor and i need a function between its fifth and itself. So, if you people have any ideas, please do solve my problem? I will be obliged for that.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think this needs to be closed, but it's very unclear what you're trying to accomplish here. Can you edit the question to include the context of "bait and switch"?

Comment: Please also clarify what you mean by "I need a function between its fifth and itself". I am assuming it refers to A minor, but then I'm wondering do you mean the key or the chord?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. To me, "bait and switch" implies a [deceptive cadence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deceptive_cadence#Interrupted_.28deceptive.29_cadence), in which V (the dominant chord) resolves to VI (in a major key it would be vi) instead of the regular i chord. So in the key of A Minor, instead of resolving E to Am, you'd play E to F.

More generally, you might try looking at some other [irregular resolutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irregular_resolution).

Comment: well, it is quite descriptive, it will take some time to read. i will get back to you in few hours. thanks for the idea.